# Why the client can't dereference the pointer in this situation?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I understand the client can manipulate the pointer to the structure in this situation, but can't dereference it. I was wondering why exactly it can't be dereferenced?

#### stack.h

```
#ifndef STACK_INCLUDED
#define STACK_INCLUDED

typedef struct Stack_T *Stack_T;

extern Stack_T stack_new(void);
extern int stack_empty( Stack_T p_stk );
extern void stack_push( Stack_T p_stk, void *p_data );
extern void *stack_pop( Stack_T p_stk );
extern void stack_free( Stack_T *p_stk );

#endif
```

#### stack.c

```
#include "stack.h"

struct Stack_T {
    int node_count;
    struct node {
        void *p_data;
        struct elem *p_link;
    } *p_head;
};
```

#### main.c

```
#include "stack.h"

int main(void)
{
    Stack_T stk;
    ...
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To be more exact, why that object can't be dereferenced in main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by "client" you mean "a source file that includes `stack.h`".

The reason is that `struct Stack_T` is not actually defined in the `stack.h` file. It's declared, the `typedef` makes sure that the compiler understands that there is going to be a `struct Stack_T` defined somewhere, but not yet.

The `stack.c` is the only module that needs to know what is *inside* a `struct Stack_T`, so the definition of the structure is inside that file.

Clients of this code don't need to know what is inside a `struct Stack_T`, so they don't see the definition.

Comment: So it's because main.c doesn't have "access" to the definition?

Comment: Correct. At the time the compiler is processing `main.c`, it can only see what is in `stack.h` (and the contents of `stack.c` is not visible).